# Trigger pipeline on different branches conditionally, according to different pipeline parameters, from a single YAML file

Tags: azure-devops, triggers, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a single YAML config file for an Azure DevOps pipeline which has the following trigger:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - develop
     - release/*
```

And I would like to be able to conditionally run it on develop, according to what pipeline parameters are selected when the pipeline is run, something like:

```
trigger:
  branches:
   (if parameter.Foo = true trigger develop)
    include:
     - develop
     (if parameter.Bar = true trigger release/*)
     - release/*
```

I looked at official Microsoft Azure DevOps documentation but could find anything similar, only that maybe something related to what I want could be achieved with Branch Policies in Azure DevOps.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Comment: Did the answer below help? If it works, you could Accept it as an Answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggers do not support IF statements. However, you may try to use conditions on the job level:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/jobs-job?view=azure-pipelines
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cstages#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops

Example:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
     - develop
     - release/*
jobs:
- job: MyJob
  displayName: My First Job
  condition: and(succeeded(), or( and( eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/develop'), eq('${{ parameters.Foo }}', true)), and( startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/release'), eq('${{ parameters.Bar }}', true))))
  workspace:
    clean: outputs
  steps:
  - script: echo My first job
```

Comment: I ended up doing some pipeline trigger settings in ADO to achieve a similar outcome to what I wanted, but thank for letting me know that triggers in YAML do not support IF statements, and for the other solution you've provided.